# Run jar file in command prompt

Tags: java, jar

How do we run a jar file in command prompt?

Answer (score 556, accepted):

Try this

```
java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar
```

Comment: this will work when the created jar file is a runnable jar.

Comment: More times when you usea a '.jar', not work correctly and you need call with a interal sentence. Thanks :)

Comment: as a note, if your application uses a web framework there maybe more params that you have to pass in, for example with dropwizard... `java -jar myapp.jar server xxx.yml`

Comment: Using these command you can run the jar file using the background process.

**nohup java -jar /web/server.jar &**

Answer (score 261):

If you dont have an entry point defined in your manifest invoking `java -jar foo.jar` will not work.

Use this command if you dont have a manifest or to run a different main class than the one specified in the manifest:

```
java -cp foo.jar full.package.name.ClassName
```

See also instructions on how to create a manifest with an entry point:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: This also works if you want to run a different class main than what is specified in the manifest.

Comment: For Developers, I think this is a better answer than Bala R's, although they should ideally be combined

Comment: I would say this should be the accepted answer not the other one.

Comment: what if i don't have an main method ? i want to use the a static method , with parameters

Comment: @MoxGeek you need a static method named `main`. I don't think there is a way arround this. You can still write your own `Main` class and import your other class from there. Extra parameters to pass to the main method just comes after your `full.package.name.ClassName`. You could also have a look to java REPL, like jshell and import what you need, this solution would feel more "scripting" style.

Answer (score 37):

`java [any other JVM options you need to give it] -jar foo.jar`

Comment: -D arguments go before the -jar! thanks I needed that

Answer (score 26):

You can run a JAR file from the command line like this:

```
java -jar myJARFile.jar
```

Comment: well done for answering 2 seconds before the accepted answer :-)