# Run an execution with several jars

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

How can I run a jar that needs several jars to work?
Let me explain, I have for example a project with a jar "`Main.jar`" but to run this `Main.jar` I need `jdom.jar`(for xml file), `jGit.jar`...

Assume we need more than two jars. How can I run my `Main.jar`?

Comment: Put the jars in the classpath (the .jar file, not the directory it lies in)

Comment: @Mehdi How are you running your Main.jar? The command line is referring to the terminal where you are executing commands. Eg. under Windows `cmd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including the needed jar files in the classpath. Something like:

```
 java -cp "Main.jar;jdom.jar;jdom.jar" MainClass
```

If you are under Windows and would like to execute the `Main.jar` with a double click, you will need to create a `.bat` file and use that one instead to run your program. The content of the `.bat` file will have the above command.

Under Unix/Linux you will create a shell file with the similar content.

Note that the `-cp` argument values will need to contain all the jars that your Main.jar is depended on.

Answer (score 1):

Run the jar with main class and add all other jars to classpath.

```
java -cp yourJars yourClass
```

see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt) for more info. See this [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html)