# Unable to execute .jar file

Tags: java, jar, javaw

I'm having a problem with running .jar files. Here's what I've observed:

- running executable .jar by doubleclicking doesn't do anything, not even start a process
- running it from cmd by typing `javaw myfile.jar` doesn't do anything as well, I've redirected STDERR but it doesn't say anything
- because of school requirements I'm developing in BlueJ, when I run my code directly from this IDE, it works and starts processes like `java.exe` or `javaw.exe`
- when I try to compile my console program from cmd and then run it by `java myclass`, it works

I'm working on Windows 7 Professional with Java SE 7u51 JDK installed. I've already tried to uninstall anything that had "java" in its name and then install only JDK or only JRE. I've also tried to run jarfix or manually delete all .jar associations in registry. I've added my JRE path to other system variables. Nothing has worked for me.

Please do you have any idea what to try next? Thank you.

**Resolved:**
Thanks to the answers I've managed to resolve the problem with doubleclicking as well. I've just had to:

1. [set](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows) the `JAVA_HOME` variable
2. restart the computer
3. run [jarfix](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/Jarfix.shtml)

Comment: Try `java -jar myfile.jar`

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt

Comment: What is the value of your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable? What does `java -version` return?

Comment: can you check when you create your jar you mentioned the main class name? did you used fatjar or other class archiver

Comment: @JUBA works fine, thank you
@DrewMacInnis doubleclick however still doesn't work, maybe the problem is in `JAVA_HOME` variable, I haven't set it, what should it contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of quick solutions:

- Use `java -jar <jar-file-name>`

  Note: This will be useful if your jar is Runnable
- Use `java -cp <jar-file-name> main-class-name`

  Note: Specify the entry point with the class-name to start execution.

Comment: When used with `-jar`, my program has thrown some exceptions, after resolving them, it finally works and starts java process. Doubleclick still doesn't work but I think I can live with that.