# packaged to jar, running in cmd, but cannot find main class

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run my java class with dependencies in the command line. And I'm used IntelliJ Idea 13 to build artifact from my project. I have a main class say "Main.java" and after the build I got a jar file like mytest.jar. The Main.java's full qualified name is like "test.Main"

But when I'm trying to run it using "java mytest.jar", it complained that cannot find main class mytest.jar.

I checked the files in the jar and it seems like I got all the dependencies I need, and the main class in the MANIFEST.MF seems also ok. And actually if I unzip the jar into "mytest" folder, and try run "java test.Main" in it I works good.

My jar file is like this:

> mytest
>
> --test
>
> ----Main.class
>
> --META-INF
>
> ----MANIFEST.NF
>
> --org... //dependencies

My MANIFEST.MF is like this:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Main-Class: test.Main

So what's your advice?

UPDATE: the Main-Class MANIFEST.MF is test.Main, I'm using a simple example in this question and forgot to change the content, sorry.

Comment: How do you execute it in the command-line? Check answers to a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt

Comment: If your main class's fully qualified name is `test.Main`, why have you specified `example.SimpleServer` in your manifest? Just fix your manifest...

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest, the `Main-Class` attribute should be `test.Main`. I haven't used Idea yet, but for example in Eclipse, you can specify a Run configuration the executable jar file will be generated with.