# how to run java file in window powershell

Tags: java, jar, window, powershell-3.0

I know there are similar questions out there but none of those solutions work for my case.
I tried to execute a Java file using Windows PowerShell.

This is what I have for Java file:

```
public class Demo1 { 
  public static void main (String arg[]){
        System.out.println("DEMO1 START RUNNING");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Unable to process");
        }
        System.out.println("DEMO1 JAVA COMPLETED.");    
    }
}
```

For easy compilation, I have copies of Demo1.java, Demo1.jar, and Demo1.class in the desktop directory.

for powershell command, I have tried:
1st attempt:  
C:..\Desktop> java Demo1.java

2nd attempt: 
C:..\Desktop> java -class Demo1.class

3rd attempt: 
C:..\Desktop> java -jar Demo1.jar

All the above attempt return this error:
**PS C:\Users\b003485\Desktop> java .\Demo1.java 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /\Demo1/java 

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .\Demo1.java 

        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 

        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 

        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 

        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 

Could not find the main class: .\Demo1.java.  Program will exit.**

Comment: You will not run .java file, you need .class file. First compile and then run. Spend sometime on learning basics.

Comment: Simply `java Demo1`. I would recommend looking at [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html).

Comment: guys, im referring to powershell here, not cmd command prompt.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! , so I noticed there was a typo with the main method header: <br>
original:  public static void main (String arg[]){

I changed to   **public static void main(String[] args)** and then compiling it  and export it to a jar file. <br>
THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT: when you exporting the file to jar, during the configuration. make sure choose your main class file or else you will run into the same problem like i did. <br>
finally
run **java -jar Demo1.jar** in powershell and it works like a charm!

Comment: Changing the variable name from `arg` to `args` has nothing to do with why your program started working. And executing a Java application in PowerShell works the same way as you would with command prompt. See [executing a jar file from command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt), and note that it uses the same command you used.