# Launching a main class with another

Tags: java

I am trying to create some simple programs that allow you to create and access accounts. I am using the `JLabel` and `JTextField` methods to do so.

How do I use one main class to launch another?

For example, if I could execute `cmd` commands through Java, then I would run the following command: `java -jar fileTwo.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you want to launch another program from your program.

If possible, you should call the `main` function of the second program from the first.

Otherwise, try [`Runtime.exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) or [`ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). Note that I've never used `ClassLoader`, so I might be interpreting the docs wrong, but it seems to be something that might accomplish you're looking for. Googling tells me that it's probably excessive to use it for a program such as yours, though, so I'd stick with `Runtime.exec()`.

Edit: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c java -jar fileTwo.jar")`, assuming your jar is named `fileTwo`. Make sure your jar is [executable](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html).

Comment: @JackKirby http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt

Comment: Thanks! That was just what needed! Everything is working now!