# Java Console Application open and run JAR file

Tags: java, windows, jar, executable-jar

How to in Java console app run JAR file and get output of it and sent commands? I need for creation controller of minecraft server. Normally is starting minecraft server with BAT file with this code:

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
```

PAUSE

How to I get this in Java console application using netbeans? WITHOUT RUN CMD.

Comment: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

Comment: Thanks! But this is for running native Windows app and I ask to run .jar file.

Comment: how about to run ```java -jar your.jar``` with code from link?

Comment: and get output from file and send commnad.

Comment: ```Runtime.exec()``` captures output from stdout. did you try that example already?

Comment: Sorry! Thanks for your answer! I understand it now!

Answer (score 1):

```
java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar
```

But this will only work if you have created runnable .jar

This has been answered here
[Run jar file in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt)

Comment: This is not capture output from JAR

Comment: I have followed this instruction and I run that jar with command above and everything works fine. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYdC5TvVv_s