# how to run jar files depend on jar files

Tags: java, linux, shell, jar

my program consist of

"javax.mail.jar"

and a simple myProgram.java (Contain Main class) ("package:com.test.myprogram")

and anotherProgram.java (contain Main class) ("package:com.test.myprogram")

I have converted it to "myprogram.jar" file

how do I run "myProgram.java" in shell? using "myprogram.jar"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a JAR file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)

Comment: Are you asking how to run a JAR that has as a dependency another JAR? If so, you need to specify how you generated that JAR and what error message you're getting. Please, check [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is in (say) "myprogram.jar" and it depends on "javax.mail.jar", then you would run it like this:

```
$ java -cp myprogram.jar:javax.mail.jar com.test.myprogram.Main
```

(On Windows, you need to use `;` instead of `:` as the classpath separator.)

However, it doesn't make a lot of sense to have "myProgram.java" and "anotherProgram.java" BOTH declare a `Main` class ... by which I assume you mean a class called `Main`.  The problem is that since both versions of the `Main` class are in the same package, compiling one source file will overwrite the `Main` class produced when you compile the other source file.

Answer (score -1):

```
 java -classpath yourjarfilename.jar yourpackagename.classname
```

Comment: If understood correctly I would expect it to work except you need to mention both `.jar` files.