# Executing java.exe from C# in Azure Function

Tags: java, c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to execute java to run a JAR file from an Azure function, but it seems like the java PATH variable isn't defined or something because Azure can't seem to find it.  Code below:

```
 Process proc = new Process();
        try
        {
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "java.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar file path and some more arguments";
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            if (proc.HasExited)
                log.Info(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

            log.Info("Java Success!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Info("Java Fail");
            log.Info(e.Message);
        }
```

Even if I remove the `proc.StartInfo.Arguments` or tell it to use `java.exe` instead of `java` I still get the same error, below:

> [Info] The system cannot find the file specified

Is calling java not supported in Azure functions?

Comment: try what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5774976/8420233) says

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK figured this out.  So far, the best way is to fully qualify the path to java.exe...

so I changed
`proc.StartInfo.FileName = java.exe";`
to
`proc.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_73\\bin\\java.exe";`

You can figure out the full path to Java using KUDU, which is https://[yourFunctionName].scm.azurewebsites.net/

If you click on Tools->DebugConsole, you can browse until you find where Java is located.

Note hard coding the path to Java is probably a bad idea so you should probably use application settings.

**Edit** Below is a link to a GitHub Repo with my final project.  The project does some other stuff, but you can see where I call Java to execute the Batik JAR.
https://github.com/osuhomebase/SVG2PNG-AzureFunction

Comment: IMHO the proper way to do this is:
`proc.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(Path.Combine("%JAVA_HOME%", "bin", "java.exe"));`

You should always use environment variable (if available) and not the absolute path of the binary :).

Comment: Hehe, I was looking at your code and then was questioning myself okay okay but how does that work, is java installed on each host then came here. Are you still using this piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

As of September 2022,

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = java.exe";
```

Worked fine for me. It appears the Azure Function Environment has the JDK installed and the JAVA PATH variable set.