# create executable jar with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a task to create `xxxxx.jar` executable file that mast be run with:

```
java xxx.jar
```

I have tried to do this with gradle by setting

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.Main'
    }
}
```

but once I run `java xxxxx.jar` I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class xxxxx.jar
```

I how ever i can run it with `java -jar xxxxx.jar` but I need to execute the file just with `java xxxxx.jar`

What can change to run it just with `java xxxxx.jar`. I suspect this might be some where in the gradle file.

Comment: Duplicate of [Run jar file in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5774970/5221149)

Comment: You cannot skip the `-jar` flag here.  What is it you need to do?

Comment: thanks for your answers. its is an interview requirement, and it is specified to send a jar that can be run in the following way:  java AppName.jar extra_params